# print md5 output in same row

Tags: bash, terminal

I want to make a txt file with the filepath of every file of a directory of a external hard disk, including the md5 sum of its head and tail and all in one row, separated by semicolons.

For example:

```
harddisc1/folder1/folder2/folder3/file.bla ; haedf0849wrzh2ewn ; 9823ueqizhrwdiuqh
harddisc1/folder1/folder5/anotherfile.blu ; 208349eoirjds ; 98w4IUOEHRAJFD
```

and so on..

I have something that works for the path and the head. But I'm not able to print the tail in the same line. Can you help me?

I use a MacBook Pro with macOS 10.13.5

code:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c "echo -n harddiscname; echo -n \"{};\"; head -c 10000 \"{}\" |
md5 echo "\;" tail -c 10000  \"{}\" |
md5" \; > /Users/Tobias/Desktop/discname.txt
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you want the md5 of head and tail instead of the whole file?

Comment: I want to compare the md5sum of the head of different directories and if they are identical, i compare there tails too so i can be sure that there are the same files in different directories. I do this to find duplicates between 30 external harddrives in somehow an efficient way. I hope this is faster than calculating the whole md5 sum of the files. The files are mainly large video photoshop files.

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. Finding identical files, e.g., can be done quite efficiently with tools such as http://www.schweikhardt.net/samefile/ Note that computing md5 is a waste if files differ as a simple comparison detects that quite early, often after reading just a few bytes.

Comment: Thank you for this tip! But i want to compare 30 external harddrives which i can not plug in all together at once in a pc. Thats why i wanted to get all the paths and md5sums from every single file of every harddrive, put them together and compare them with a matlab script i wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My system has `md5sum` which might behave slightly different than `md5`.  For example, it tries to print the file name after the hash value.  In the sample below my example would print `hashhashhash... -`.  FYI

```
find . -type f -exec \
        bash -c 'h=`head -c 10000 "{}" | md5sum`;\
                 t=`tail -c 10000 "{}" | md5sum`;\
                 echo "{} ; $h ; $t"' \;
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This works. I just deleted the "sum" in your code and added the "> /Users/Tobias/Desktop/filename.txt"